# Java mkdir will not work

Tags: java, file, directory

I have this method where I am trying to create a sub directory into the stations folder. All needed directories are made before this method is called. All folders have the normal positions and are not hidden.

```
private void moveFiles(){
    String[] dates = getDates();
    //File oldFile = new File("/stations/CurrentFiles/");
    File newFile = new File("/stations/" + dates[0].replaceAll("/", "-") + "-" + dates[1].replaceAll("/", "-") + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "/");
    if(!newFile.exists()){
        if(newFile.mkdir()){
            System.out.println(newFile.isHidden());
        }else{
            System.out.println("error");
            System.out.println(newFile.isHidden());
        }
    }
}
```

Not understanding what could make it not make the directory.

Comment: Will not work how?  What error (if any) are you getting?

Comment: An error is not being thrown the directory is just not being made. I used the same format i used to create the station directory and it work 100% of the tests i did.

Comment: Does the parent directory exist? Have you tried `mkdirs` instead? (And is /stations/ really a directory in your filesystem root?)

Comment: Does the user account with which you are running this program have write access to the parent directory? (i.e. can you create the directory from the command line with the same account or not?)

Comment: station directory already exist before calling this method. I tried both mkdir and mkdirs and both do not work for some reason.

Comment: I can create a directory through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure you have write permissions for that directory; try `newFile.canWrite()`.

Comment: I inserted System.out.println(newFile.canWrite()); under the error printing and it showed false. How would I go about changing this if possible.

Comment: If this is on your own system, try running your program as root/administrator. If its on a system where you don't have superuser access, consider writing to a different directory.

Comment: The station directory I made to place all the files needed for the program so I need if possible for everything to stay in that one folder.

Comment: If you have a file manager, try right clicking on the stations directory and changing properties. Also try leaving of that last / in the `new File` declaration.

Comment: If I was able to make a parent directory why can I not make a child directory?